# validation question for webform validate

Tags: webforms

I need to validate that a field does not contain only numbers. in other words it can have some numbers but must have some letters as well. Can someone help me with the regex to do that?

I am using webforms 7.x-3.18+3 and webforms validation 7.x 1.1

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps you'll need to follow:

1. Go to your webform
2. Select the "form validation" button.
3. under the "Add a validation rule" select "Regular expression, case-sensitive"
4. For the regex, you can use `^\d*$` and check the negate rule box below

OR

1. Go to your webform
2. Select the "form validation" button.
3. under the "Add a validation rule" select "Regular expression, case-sensitive"
4. For the regex, you can use `[^\d]+`

Comment: Thanks! the second option worked since I didnt have the negate rule box.